# How do I set a class (related sfml game development)

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm reading the book "SFML Game Development by Jan Haller, Henrik Vogelius Hansson, Artur Moreira", and I'm stuck on the very front pages.

[image]

[image]

It seems I must set up some sort of class...
I just don't know where to put these codes in pictures.

I mean I can't put these codes in a "main" function right?
so what do I do?

Comment: What you do is get a good book or tutorial about the basics of C++, and learn those, before trying to use some external library like SFML.

Comment: You should learn C++ before you start learning libraries that use C++.

Answer (score 4):

Right, it seems like you are trying to learn how to run when you don't know how to walk. It looks like the book is using C++, if you don't know the basic of C++ I recommend you to learn those basics first because classes are kind of an advanced topic.

But I can explain some of the code for you, it seems like the book has created a class type called Game. A class is basically a user defined type that consists of primitive-data types(types that are created by the authors of C++). A class is almost like a structure. Inside the class you have what you call keywords such as "private" or "public" or "protected". These keywords are called access specifiers, which you can put member attributes and member functions inside them. Member attributes means the data-types that make up the class and member functions are functions that is a part of the class. For example, a car, the member attributes would be the tire, the frames, the steering wheel and the member functions would be starting up the car, how the wheel moves etc.

Anyway these access specifiers choose how you can access these attributes and functions. The private access specifier makes it so that only the class can directly access the attributes and functions inside of it and the public access specifier makes it so that the attributes and functions can be accessed outside of the class.

So that is all I can explain for you now, it is best for you to look at other source to get the grip of the intermediate stuff and the basic stuff before you tackle this.

Some sources:

https://www.udemy.com/course/beginning-c-plus-plus-programming/ - This is a full udemy course on C++ it teaches the basic to advanced areas.

C++ Primer Fifth Edition by Stanley B.Lippman, Josee Lajoie and Barbara E.Moo is a good reference book for C++ basic and advanced topics.

There are free options as well:

Lectures in Edx.org
Code Academy
https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/
Youtube courses etc.

So before you tackle this make sure you have the basics first and use the sources above.

I hope this was helpful, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are really asking how to set up a [developer environment](https://stephencoakley.com/2015/01/21/guide-setting-up-a-simple-c-development-environment-on-windows). I assume you use windows.

If you just want to test if some code works you can also test run it on [compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/)

Comment: No, my environment is fine. I think my problem is I don't have a good c++ basic, so I don't know what the codes in the pictures meaning.

Comment: But in your question you write "I just don't know where to put these codes in pictures". Could you please update your question to something that can be answered?

Comment: my bad, I've revised it, hope it works

Answer (score 0):

Just put it after `main()`. It is called declarations and they should be put outside of all other functions.

Comment: Why after? If you declare stuff after `main()`, you won't be able to use it in `main()`, and then what's the point of it?

Comment: The class definition also contains definitions to the functions, so the compiler will have no problems with finding the functions as long as there is a definition of the functions before main.

Comment: But you said "declarations", not definitions, indicating to put declarations after `main()`, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @underscore_d I sad declarations when I was talking about the declarations. The definitions (not declarations) should go before main and the declarations can go anywhere you like.